# how to search a date in sql only in month

Tags: php, mysql

i have made table holidays with a column of "description and date_stamp (format yyyy-mm-dd)"
example value:

- row 1 : New Year     , 2013-12-31
- row 2 : Christmas   , 2013-12-25
- row 3 : My Birthday , 2013-01-18

what should be the query in order display only the selected month? example if i select january. all the dates in january should be displayed.

and on my html . i made a dropbox of months from january to december

```
<select>
      <option selected value="1">January</option>
      <option value="2">February</option>
      <option value="3">March</option>
      <option value="4">April</option>
      <option value="5">May</option>
      <option value="6">June</option>
      <option value="7">July</option>
      <option value="8">August</option>
      <option value="9">September</option>
      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="11">November</option>
      <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE MONTH(date_stamp)=2;
```

Comment: oh my god. you saved me. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**MONTH**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function to perform this.

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE MONTH(date_stamp) = '<month>';
```

Answer (score 1):

try

> select date-colomn-name as holiday from table where MONTH(date-colomn-name) =1

returns the dates in january.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE MONTH(date_stamp)='2'; //for month february
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE RIGHT(LEFT(date_stamp,7),2) = '02'; //for february
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('date_stamp')))= 'month(1-12)';
```